# Subsetting data from a data frame using R so that the data is valid for one condition and not valid for the remaining conditions

Tags: r

I have data frame like this

```
Subject      stim       GZMB   TNF  IFNg      
HC           no stim    1        1     0
EC           1100       0        1     0
CH           no stim    0        0     1
```

I would like to subset the data such that I get the subject and stim values for which GZMB is 1 and all the others (TNF, IFNg) are zero.

Comment: Please [edit your question as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you could use:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
        mutate(Sum=colSums(.[,-c(1,2)])) %>% 
         filter(Sum==1  & GZMB==1)
  Subject stim GZMB TNF IFNg Sum
1    1100    0    1   0   NA   1
```

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(Subject = c("no", "1100", "no"), stim = c("stim", 
"0", "stim"), GZMB = c(1L, 1L, 0L), TNF = c(1L, 0L, 0L), IFNg = c(0L, 
NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HC", "EC", "CH"
))
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you explain (.[,-c(1,2)]) part of the code?

Comment: This takes column sums except for the first and second columns. `.`. That is similar to `mydata[,-c(1,2)]`  ie select minus the first and second columns.